# Is there any way to connect Bitbucket with SonarQube using githook to automatically check pull requests without Jenkins/Bamboo?

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, githooks, sonarqube-scan

I want to connect Bitbucket server (4.14) with SonarQube (6.3.1) to launch a sonar execution when any user create a pull request in Bitbucket.

Is there any way to connect Bitbucket with Sonar and launch the Sonar build scan using githook?

> I know that that the best practice is to launch Sonar from Bamboo or Jenkins but I need a workaround before my company updates Bamboo for support pull request feature.

Thanks!

Comment: the only thing i am aware of, is that you could do is a local analysis against sonar, which you could use. You could also implement this like a githook (time consuming) - so it will be done automatically. But my recommendation is, to set up a jenkins. Because when you care about sonar, you should also care about a Continous Integration, running tests etc.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner I edited my post, I need a workaround before my company updates Bamboo for support pull request feature. Cand you recommend me how to implement this feature using githooks?Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try out the [SonarQube Stash (BitBucket) plugin](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash).